# How to make this tensorflow code not depend on batch_size?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, ])
b = tf.stack([c[i, a[i]] for i in xrange(batch_size)])
```

If we replace the `batch_size` with `None`, there is no way we can use `xrange(None)`, how can we produce `b` then?

`c` has shape `(None,6)` here, and the value of `a` is from `0` to `5`

It seems that `tf.foldl` might give me the right solution, could anyone explain that to me? Thank you so much!

I am sorry for the confusion, but I mean, can I do

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, ])
b = tf.stack([c[i, a[i]] for i in xrange(None)])
```

Answer (score 0):

your details are prone to confusion. Hopefully you want to do this

```
variable_rows    = 1
variable_columns = 6
batch_size       = 4
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[batch_size,variable_rows, variable_columns])
b = []
for i in range(variable_columns):
    b.extend([i+1])
c = []
for i in range(batch_size):
    c.append([b])

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(a,feed_dict={a:c}))
```

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, but I mean changing batch_size to None (undetermined length).

Answer (score 0):

In this case batch_size is a python variable, not a Tensor, so rules for normal python variables apply (like no xrange(None)).

The operation you want to do seems to be equivalent to `tf.gather(c, a)` or something similar using `tf.strided_slice`.